Page Not Found in Netlify
I am currently building a React website and I created a PageNotFound component and integrated on my Routes which works fine but when deployed on Netlify, it displays the default netlify page not found not mine.
`
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'; 
    import errorPage from '../assets/images/pageNotFound.jpg'; 
    import { Button } from '../components';

export const PageNotFound = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <section className='flex flex-col justify-center px-2'>
        <div className='flex flex-col items-center my-4'>
          <p className='text-7xl text-gray-700 font-bold my-10 dark:text-white'>
            404, Oops!
          </p>
          <div className='max-w-lg'>
            <img className='rounded' src={errorPage} alt='404 page not found' />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='flex justify-center my-4'>
          <Link to='/'>
            <Button props='Back to Reel' />
          </Link>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  );
};

`
Do I need any settings to be done or netlify or what?

You need to redirect all requests to index.html by creating _redirects file in the root directory of your react app and add the following into it:

/*  /index.html   200

